# local variable scope vs lifetime -- is it guaranteed when the destructor is called?

Tags: c++, scope, destructor, lifetime, raii

This question is for understanding the effect of a class that's used for RAII; specifically if a variable of that class is allocated at the beginning of a function, is the destructor only called when exiting the function (by either `return` or `throw`) or can a conforming compiler call the destructor earlier? That is: in a C++ function, is it possible for the compiler to re-use space on the stack if a variable isn't used beyond a certain point, or is this strictly controlled by '{...}'?

Here's an example, with three variants of code for controlling scope/lifetime of a local variable. Is it possible for a conforming implementation to give the same output for f1(), f2(), f3(); or is the output given below guaranteed? (f1(), f2(), f3() are identical except for where local scope `{...}` are used.)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Raii {
public:
  explicit Raii(const std::string& name)
    : name_(name) {
    std::cout << "Construct " << name_ << std::endl;
  }
  ~Raii() {
    std::cout << "Destruct  " << name_ << std::endl;
  }
  std::string name_;
};

void f1() {
  [[maybe_unused]] Raii r1("f1-one");
  std::cout << "after f1-one" << std::endl;
  [[maybe_unused]] Raii r2("f1-two");
  std::cout << "after f1-two" << std::endl;
}

void f2() {
  {
    [[maybe_unused]] Raii r1("f2-one");
  }
  std::cout << "after f2-one" << std::endl;
  [[maybe_unused]] Raii r2("f2-two");
  std::cout << "after f2-two" << std::endl;
}

void f3() {
  {
    [[maybe_unused]] Raii r1("f3-one");
  }
  std::cout << "after f3-one" << std::endl;
  {
    [[maybe_unused]] Raii r2("f3-two");
  }
  std::cout << "after f3-two" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "=== f1" << std::endl;
  f1();
  std::cout << std::endl << "=== f2" << std::endl;
  f2();
  std::cout << std::endl << "=== f3" << std::endl;
  f3();
  std::cout << "== end" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and I get this output with both g++ and clang++:

```
=== f1
Construct f1-one
after f1-one
Construct f1-two
after f1-wo
Destruct  f1-two
Destruct  f1-one

=== f2
Construct f2-one
Destruct  f2-one
after f2-one
Construct f2-two
after f2-two
Destruct  f2-two

=== f3
Construct f3-one
Destruct  f3-one
after f3-one
Construct f3-two
Destruct  f3-two
after f3-two
== end
```

Comment: Destructor must be called at the end of the scope (and in reverse order). The compiler cannot reorder code here as it would result in observable behavior (output would not be the same).

Comment: My question wasn't about reordering the code, but whether the compiler was allowed to add "{...}" around a block of code when it knows that the variables declared in that section of code aren't used later in the code. I *think* that the answer is "no": the scope and lifetime of a local variable are the same (same for a constructor that appears only inside a single expression).

Comment: Here variables are use until the end of scope because the destructor print a message.

Comment: I know that my sample code shows that the destructor happens at end of scope. My question is whether the standard requires that the destructor be at the end of scope if the variable's last use is earlier than the end of scope. That is, is the compiler allowed to say "the variable isn't used beyond this point, so I can invoke its destructor and reuse that space on the stack".

Comment: Simple answer : if the destructor does have any observable effect, it cannot be moved. To know if a compiler does that kind of optimization, you will probably have to look at assembly code.